# Form POST not showing in controller

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, codeigniter

I am working with CodeIgniter, and I am trying to create a dynamically generated table that includes a checkbox, with values set to the id numbers of the row, in the first column of the row.  When a single or multiple checkbox is checked, and the button clicked, I am trying to bring up a second form which consists of a couple of select fields and a textarea.

Ultimately, when I submit the form, I want the values of the checkboxes to be sent to my controller.  However, currently I am only getting a false value when I check the values of the POST field in my controller.

Here is my current view code:

```
<form class="form" role="form" name="ticket_view" id="ticket_view" action="<?php echo site_url('example_controller/example_method'); ?>">
        <div class='table-responsive text-left'>
           <table class='table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed supportTable'>
                <thead>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                    <th>Source</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php foreach($examples as $example): ?>
                        <?php if ($example->type == "test): ?>
                            <tr class="<?php echo alternator('oddRow', '');?>">
                                <td class="text-center" style="width:60px;"><input type="checkbox" value="<?=$example->id;?>" name="supportTicketId[]" class="supportLogCheck"></td>
                                <td><a href=<?php echo site_url("example_controller/example_method/" . $example->idd); ?>>SUP-<?php echo $example->id; ?></a></td>
                                <td class="text-center">
                                    <?php if ( ! $example->claimed): ?>
                                        <span class="label label-danger">Unclaimed</span>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <span class="label label-success">Claimed</span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                               </td>
                               <td><?php if ($example->voicemail): ?>Voicemail <?php else: ?>Email <?php endif; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" id="firstButton" href="javascript:void(0);">First Button</a>
        </div>
        <div id="secondForm" class="alert alert-info col-md-4 col-md-offset-4" style="display:none; margin-top:10px;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="closeIssue">Issue:</label>
                <select name="issue" id="issue" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select an Issue</option>
                    <?php foreach ($issues as $issue): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo ($e->emailIssueId); ?>"><?php echo ($issue->emailIssueDescription); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <label for="closeAction">Action:</label>
                <select name="action" id="action" class="form-control">
                    <option value="">Select an Action</option>
                    <?php foreach ($actions as $action): ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo ($action->emailActionId); ?>"><?php echo ($action->emailActionDescription); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="assignNote">Note:</label>
                <textarea name="assignNote" id="assignNote" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="text-center">
                <input class="btn btn-primary" name="secondButton" type="submit" id="secondButton" value="second button">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

So, in a nutshell, the table is wrapped in a form.  The first button slides down a 
div that is orginally hidden, that contains other form fields and a submit button.  I want, when that submit button is clicked, for all form fields to post, including the id numbers of the checkboxes that are checked.

Any ideas why this isn't working?  Any better suggestions?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Can you post your controller code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined method on your form, so it's probably passing the values via GET. You need to add the method="post" attribute in your form tag.

Comment: Thank you, sir.  Always fun to waste an hour over something as simple as that!